# Problema con una transaccion

Tags: genexus

tengo dos objetos transaction con sus respectivos ID que al compilar como es lo obvio crea sus respectivas tablas, sucede que al hacer la relacion de las dos objetos colocando el id de una tabla como id foranea del otra y sucede que no me hace la relacion que el id inferida por lo que genexus toma el id y la deja interna y no hace la relacion

Comment: Que Base de datos estas utilizando?

Comment: Hola en realidad yo uso Genexus y el problema que te presento se da al compilar genexus

Comment: debes revisar tu ambiente para seleccionar la DB, o si estas usando la trial por omisión tu db está en MS sqlserver express, puedes aumentar el error que te está soltando.

Comment: aumenta la version de tu genexus por favor

Comment: La version del genexus que estoy usando es la version 15 con licencia y no hay problema con la base de datos mi problema es en la KB(base de conocimiento) al desarrollar el programa, resulta que en genexus al relacionar dos objetos transaction cada una con su respectivo ID(llave primaria) resulta que al enviar el id como llave foranea a la tabla que quiero relacionar el genexus de manera interna infiere la llave y no hace la relacion aclaro el problema es en genexus y no en la base de datos

Comment: ¿Podrías poner tus transacciones y el resultado en tablas que obtienes así como el resultado esperado?

Comment: Con gusto, soy nuevo en este foro si fueras tan amable para adjuntarte la imagen a algun correo porque por este medio veo que no se puede adjuntar imagen